# GET request in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Hi guys I had used this code my AngularJS app to execute a GET request, now I want to use it in Angular I have some problems with update it can anyone help me ?

script :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://---:8080/api/v1/users")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        $scope.AfficherMap = AfficherMap;
        console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR:", response);
    });
```

html:

```html
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" style="width: 250px;">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="AfficherMap(user.id)">
        <a>{{user.id}} {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? One thing I see is AfficherMap is not defined anywhere. Need more info.

Comment: no AfficherMap is defined but this is an AngularJs structure and I think it will not work in Angular

Comment: Are you trying to use AngularJS code in an Angular 2+ project ?

Comment: @SuatKarabacak yes

Comment: It will not work. These two are different things you need to start from beginning.

Comment: my app is developped by AngularJs I will not develop an application with angular I want just to know the defferences it's just for a school project but I don't know a lot about angular

Comment: Like @Phix request, you need to give more info in order to get the right answer. Let start by describing the problem, what is going on? what and where is the error?, you need to add what you have try, the angular code that correspond to the angularjs code you post

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this way...
Make a get function in UserService:

```
constructor(http:HttpClient){}

getUsers(){
  return this.http.get("api_url");
}
```

Now In your component call this function.

```
constructor(private userService: UserService){

}
ngOninit(){
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((res)=>{

 console.log(res); // This is your users list...
 this.users =  res;
});
```

}

Now In your html

```
<div  style="width: 250px;">
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
        <a (click)="AfficherMap(user.id)">{{user.id}} {{user.firstName}- 
                  {{user.lastName}}
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS(1.x) and Angular(2+) are  totally different frameworks, in Angular(2+) you will need to use HttpClient module to do an HTTP call more details on the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Find a suggestion for your code:

```
getUsers() {
  this.api.getUsersCall()
    .subscribe(users => {
      for (const u of (users as any)) {
        this.users.push({
          name: u.name,
          username: u.username
        });
      }
    });
}
```

given that `api` is an instance of the `APIService` you need to create a module for it and declare it in your component class with the specifier `private`, `APIService` module will contains the definition of `getUsersCall`:

```
getUsersCall() {
   return this.http.get("http://---:8080/api/v1/users");
}
```